# Order of field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm working on some algebra exercises and I'm really struggling with finite fields. I'm currently working on the following:

find the splitting field let's say F of a cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ and to find the degree of the extension $[F:\mathbb{Z}_{11}]$.

I've determined that the splitting field is F$=\mathbb{Z}_{11}/(f)$ where $(f)$ is the ideal generated by $f$. Now i'm stumped because I'm not sure how to figure out the order of the extension. My guess would be 3 because cubic polynomial but it's just a guess. Any hints/help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe this is true for the polynomial you're considering, and you probably know this, but just in case, typically, the degree of the splitting field extension of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ is $n!$. For example, the degree of the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over rationals is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Z_{11}$.

The extension field $E = {\Bbb Z}_{11}[x]/\langle f\rangle$ contains a zero of $f$, namely the residue class $\alpha = \bar x + \langle f\rangle$.
This gives $\alpha^3+a\alpha^2+b\alpha + c=0$, so $\alpha^3 = -a\alpha^2-b\alpha-c$, and the extension field is
$E = \{u\alpha^2+v\alpha+w\mid u,v,w\in{\Bbb Z}_{11}\}$ with degree $[E:\Bbb Z_{11}]=3$.
In particular, if $f$ is primitive, the powers of $\alpha$ are exactly the nonzero elements of $E$.

NB: $f(\bar x) = f(x +⟨f⟩)=f(x)+⟨f⟩=⟨f⟩=\bar 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This cleared it up I think. So the main takeaway is solve for the highest power of the root and i have a basis right? Could you just please explain "E=Z11[x]/⟨f⟩ contains a zero of f, namely the residue class α=x¯+⟨f⟩"? why is that residue class contain the zero of f? and what does the bar over x mean?

Comment: @Wuestenfux: your notation seems to me to be non-standard. Surely $\bar{x}=x+\langle f\rangle$, so that $\alpha=\bar{x}$? [I agree it comes to the same thing, but why add $\langle f\rangle$ twice?]